# Vue: avoid repeating calculations

Tags: loops, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a loop, where I need to evaluate the same process in several HTML elements. It looks like this:

```html
<template v-for="(week, wix) in weeks">
  <td v-for="(day, dix) in week.Days" :class="{delDate : moment(order.DeliveryDate).diff(moment(day.Date), 'days') == 0}">
      <v-icon v-if="dix==0 && wix==0 && moment(order.DeliveryDate).diff(moment(day.Date), 'days') < 0">fa-chevron-left</v-icon>
      <v-icon v-if="dix==6 && wix==1 && moment(order.DeliveryDate).diff(moment(day.Date), 'days') > 0">fa-chevron-right</v-icon>
  </td>
</template>
```

As you can see, I calculate the difference between 2 dates 3 times to evaluate the same value.

In a programming language, I'd just put the result in a variable, and use it in all 3 places, but can this be done somehow in Vue?

Is the best way to separate those inner `<td>` in its own component? and then calculate it once in a container template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend computing a new array that contains the pre-calculated dates (move the calculation from the template into a computed property, e.g., named `myWeeks`):

```js
export default {
  //...
  computed: {
    myWeeks() {
      return this.weeks.map((week, weekIndex) => {
        return {
          ...week,
          myDays: week.Days.map((day, dayIndex) => {
            const deliveryDueDate = deliveryDate.diff(moment(day.Date), 'days')

            return {
              ...day,
              onDelivery: deliveryDueDate === 0,
              beforeDelivery: (dayIndex === 0 && weekIndex === 0) && (deliveryDueDate < 0),
              afterDelivery: (dayIndex === 6 && weekIndex === 1) && (deliveryDueDate > 0),
            }
          })
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your template, you could use the computed `myWeeks` without calculation clutter:

```html
<template v-for="week in myWeeks">
  <td v-for="day in week.myDays" :class="{delDate: day.onDelivery}">
    <v-icon v-if="day.beforeDelivery">fa-chevron-left</v-icon>
    <v-icon v-if="day.afterDelivery">fa-chevron-right</v-icon>
  </td>
</template>
```

Comment: Yea..  I think this would be the proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method under your data methods property like this:

```
data: {
 methods: {
    calculateDifference(order, day) {
      return  moment(order.DeliveryDate).diff(moment(day.Date), 'days'); 
    }    
  }
}
```

If you want to cache result for same input parameters, you can use computed like this:

```js
data: {
  computed: {
    calcDifference() {
      return (order, day) => {
        window.iterations++
        return moment(order.DeliveryDate).diff(moment(day.Date), 'days')
      }
    },
  },
},
```

And then it can be used in your template:

```html
<template v-for="(week, wix) in weeks">
  <td v-for="(day, dix) in week.Days" :class="{delDate : calculateDifference(order, day) == 0}">
    <v-icon v-if="dix==0 && wix==0 && calculateDifference(order, day) < 0">fa-chevron-left</v-icon>
    <v-icon v-if="dix==6 && wix==1 && calculateDifference(order, day) > 0">fa-chevron-right</v-icon>
  </td>
</template>
```

Comment: Well this just encapsulates the calculation in a function..
The same date-difference will still be calculated 3 times right?

Comment: Well if you want to cache result, then use computed properties. Check updated answer

Comment: Yes, that does seem to work with a few tweaks: The computed property must be set slightly different than your example.
Its a bit hacky but the calculation only happens around 5000 times in mhy code and it would happen thrice as often without this..  Not sure this is the best way, but it works.